# turning a *pointer elements to an 1D array

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

The below c++ [code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterators-c-stl/) is an example that how we can print the element from a vector.

```
 #include<iostream> 
#include<iterator> // for iterators 
#include<vector> // for vectors 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
    vector<int> ar = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 

    // Declaring iterator to a vector 
    vector<int>::iterator ptr; 

    // Displaying vector elements using begin() and end() 
    cout << "The vector elements are : "; 
    for (ptr = ar.begin(); ptr < ar.end(); ptr++) 
        cout << *ptr << " "; 

    return 0;     
}
```

My question is that how we can transform the element from the ptr*, and make it a 1D array?

the elements of the array will depend on the number of elements i get from *ptr.

for example, my output array would be like this:

```
int array[i] ={ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Comment: What is `it*`? Please, as a new user here, start with the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Generally the iteration loop is written `for (ptr = ar.begin(); ptr != ar.end(); ptr++)`. I don't see why `'<'` wouldn't also work, but you don't see the reference cites use it.

Comment: Are you trying to create a 1D array from `ar` or do you just want the exact output `int array[i] ={ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }` from what you have? (and recall there are no VLA's in C++ except by non-standard extension)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a pointer to the data space of the vector using [`std::vector::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data)

```
int *array = ar.data(); // Notice the pointer notation and please avoid name 'array'

for( int i =0; i < ar.size(); i++) {
   std::cout << array[i] <<'\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ptr` is a an [iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) to vector elements. It simply gives the address where the element is stored in memory. You can read the value stored in the memory by dereferencing it i.e. `*ptr`.

[image]

If you want to create array out of your vector, you need to know the size of array at compile time, but you can use dynamiclly allocated memory instead here is an example:

```
int* arr = new int [vec.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
{
    arr[i] = vec[i];
}

delete [] arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use data() function of vector to get internal data of vector, but it is not recommended way.

For e.g. 
int* ptr = ar.data();

Refer below link for [] operator
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-data-function-in-c-stl/